# Using Unity IoC Container

Tags: unity-container

Can someone help me with this? I'm trying to use Unity IoC for injection. Here's the code:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer()
                                .RegisterType<IBaseModel, EmployeeModel>()
                                .RegisterType<IProxyObjectAdapter, EmployeeProxyObjectAdapter>()
                             .RegisterType<IAdventureWorksRepository<IProxyObjectAdapter>,AdventureWorksWCFRepository<IProxyObjectAdapter>>();
```

Unity is complaining at that last line. Here's the error message:

> 'AdventureWorksManagement.ServiceAgents.AdventureWorksWCFRepository'
>   cannot be used as type parameter 'TTo'
>   in the generic type or method
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer,
>   params
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InjectionMember[])'.
>   There is no implicit reference
>   conversion from
>   'AdventureWorksManagement.ServiceAgents.AdventureWorksWCFRepository'
>   to
>   'AdventureWorksManagement.ServiceAgents.IAdventureWorksRepository'.    C:\My Development\My Testing
>   Ground\MyTesting
>   Ground\AdventureWorksManagement\ModelView\EmployeeViewModel.cs    94  33  AdventureWorksManagement

Here's the class definition:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Repository for WCF agents
    /// </summary>
    public class AdventureWorksWCFRepository<T> : IAdventureWorksRepository<IBaseModel> where T: IProxyObjectAdapter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// WCF service end
        /// </summary>
        private readonly AdvWorksManagementService.EmployeeServiceContractClient servicePoint;

        /// <summary>
        /// Adapter used to translate WCF proxy objects to domain objects
        /// </summary>
        private T proxyobjectAdapter;

     .....
```

Please advice.
dormantroot

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct. You're mapping:

IAdventureWorksRepository<IProxyObjectAdapter> -> AdventureWorksWCFRepository<IProxyObjectAdapter>

However, in the code definition, AdventureWorkdsWCFRepository<T> implements IAdventureWorksRepository<**IBaseModel**>. Which is not the interface you're trying to map from. I suspect that IBaseModel was supposed to be "T" in the code.

Comment: chris: Programmatically  this is what I do:   IAdventureWorksRepository<IBaseModel> serviceAgent = new AdventureWorksWCFRepository<IProxyObjectAdapter>(new EmployeeProxyObjectAdapter());                                                         How could I achieve the same with Unity?